# What is the max picture width and height in bootstrap 4 grid class col-4. commands to help reduce blury images

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi so I wanted to put 3 screenshots on 3 columns in one row like step 1,2,3 I wanted to make them all the same size. I was wondering what's the max width, height I could put before it gets stretch or compress or something (using bootstrap grid col-4). Also is there a command that helps reduce blurry picture. My pictures are a little bigger (not too big but bigger than it's suppose to be so it gets a litte blurry. so for example 300px width 300px height

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking entirely depends on the pixels of your said screenshots. The smaller the pixel dimension, the smaller width and height before it starts to get too pixelated. Generally you can optimize pictures pretty neatly for web by using either Photoshop, similar or online tools.

Back in the old days (actually not that old), people used to say 72dpi/ppi (dots/pixel per inch) would be the optimal use for web, and 300dpi/ppi would be optimal for print. It honestly doesn't matter what the dpi/ppi is for web unless you are going to optimize for retina displays, in which case you'd want a better quality image than normal. You can for instance use media queries for that to check what the pixel ratio on a certain device should be before you change your pictures to a higher pixel resolution scale.

Example:

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
(min-resolution: 144dpi){ 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

This example along with more information about retina displays can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/).

Normally when you're thinking webdesign / webdevelopment, you'll have a design guide / documentation, dictating the exact dimensions for x,y,z images on a certain page / pages.
My advice would be to think more about the overall memory size of the image. You can have nicely optimized images for practically any dimension at 200kb in size. Too heavy images will affect your page performance hugely in a negative way as the loading speed will be significally longer.